# How to create this selector

Tags: jquery

I want create a selector like this on clicking on a div it must show other options like in image and after selecting another option it must show the selected value in div.

[image]

this image is from  [Google translator](http://translate.google.com/#sk/en/)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am thinking how to do this

Comment: Don't you try before asking?

Comment: done but not get any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/VuMkW/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#lang-from").click(function () {
    $("#lang-content").slideToggle(350);
  });

  $("#lang-content li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#lang-content").slideUp(350);
    $("#lang-from span").text($(this).text());
  });

});
```

Comment: This is working properly. 1 more thing 1 want is to show 5 data items in each line

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/VuMkW/1/

Comment: Thanks got the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="drop-button">
    From: LANGUAGE
    <ul id="drop-content">
        <li>OPTION</li>
        <li>OPTION</li>
        <li>OPTION</li>
        <li>OPTION</li>
        <li>OPTION</li>
        <li>OPTION</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    #drop-content { display: none; }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#drop-button").toggle(function() {
            $("#drop-content").fadeIn(350);
        }, function() {
            $("#drop-content").fadeOut(350);
        });
    });
</script>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bzkM/8/

Should work.

Comment: using <li>OPTION</li> showing data only in one line i want 6 lines of data

Comment: Sorry mate, missed a double quote there, should be working now.

Comment: Yes it is working properly but not able to select perticular item value

Comment: Thanks for reply i got the result

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer as the correct one.

Comment: This time @A.V gave the desired result.